# Unable to connect Groovy-raspbian with arduino Mega ADK & Leonardo

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon partner I'm trying to follow the example Hello World in Rosserial/tutorials but I'being given the same with the two Arduino:

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1390504719.732367] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

I have looked for fixing it but I don't find something that could help me.

Anyone could help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121571/unable-to-connect-groovy-raspbian-with-arduino-mega-adk-&-leonardo/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-01-23**:
Have you updated rosserial recently?

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-01-23**:
We work with some many differents raspberry. This one has been set up a few days ago , less than a week.  Following as always the tutorial. Problems with new versions maybe?  Thanks for your interest

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-01-26**:
Thanks you for your interest. i´m telling you tomorrow. We´re trying it in the student´s raspberry. If not, we´ll start from the beginning again.

EDIT: Remaking ros_lib was a solution for us in this case. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try remaking your ros_lib.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2